# Moving development from 100% Windows scaling to 150% chops WinForms window

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, scaling, dpi

I use C# Winforms in Visual Studio 2010. Since I've upgraded my laptop from the old 1366 x 768 resolution laptop to a new laptop with a 1920x1080 resolution, I noticed a problem when continuing development on the new laptop. I isolated the issue down to the new 150% Windows OS-wide scaling (Windows on the old laptop used 100% scaling). When I run the program, the right side of the window is strangely chopped off.

Here's the working version on the old laptop (1000 pixels wide, or 1500 pixels in 150% scaled Windows mode):

[image: old]

And here's the new version on the new laptop with the chopped window (1286 pixels wide, when it should be 1500 due to the 150% scaling).

[image: new]

Upon immediately loading the project into the new 150% scaled Windows setup and running the program, it appears to work fine, but as soon as you move one of the buttons so that VS updates the designer code (button 5 was moved as you can see), and then run, the window is chopped.

Even when manually going into the Form1.Designer.cs code, and adjusting the ClientSize to a stupid high horizontal value like `ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(3000, 709);` results in a window width that is limited to 1286 pixels at most. (Not so) coincidentally, 1286 is around 1920 / 1.5.

Basically, what the heck is going on? This appears like a bug with VS's scaling management. To be clear, the problem occurs when moving development from a 100% Windows scaled screen to a 150% Windows scaled screen, on any system. You don't need two laptops to reproduce the problem, it can all be reproduced on a single laptop (but make sure you log out and into Windows after switching from/to 100% or 150%).

Finally, to be clear, I know about setting the DPI-aware setting to true using an `app.manifest` file. Although this allows clearer text and solves the chopped window problem, I do NOT want to go this route due to inconsistent changes in my program's GUI such as overlapping controls and misplaced items on some setups.

Comment: You may want to consider using a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-arranging-controls-on-windows-forms-using-a-tablelayoutpanel) to position the buttons instead of absolute positions. That solves problems like this.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: For the main issue, it's the size of the window that is truncated, rather than a problem with the positions of the controls.

Comment: Everything is anchored to the top left. Either you need to anchor to the correct side (top right, bottom left, ect. The middle 3 will still be a problem though) or use a grid so the anchor points move with the form size.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: The problem still happens when you anchor each button to its appropriate portion of the window (left to left, top-right to top-right etc. etc. The buttons are still chopped off in the final window when run.

Comment: That's why you use a TableLayoutPanel with columns and rows by percentage.  Developing on a non-100% scale is usually fraught with peril.

Comment: @LarsTech: I can almost guarantee it would still be chopped off.

Comment: Umm, no.  You Dock.Fill the panel and set your columns and rows with the correct percentages.

Comment: @LarsTech: Okay I tried, looks like you're right, they're not chopped off. However, the window is still limited to 1286 pixels width. So in my case, even with controls being placed in proportion to the window's size, with a smaller window, they would overlap and cause problems. This is a bug with Winforms, no doubt about it.

Comment: You should probably look to use WPF instead then.

Comment: @LarsTech: Project's too big to move over. I've found two half-solutions. First is upgrading to VS 2017 (which allows you to force 100% scaling in VS Forms designer even in 150% Windows scaling), or Second: Keeping with VS 2010 but making sure Windows is set to 100% scaling. Neither is ideal, but there we go.

Comment: The form gets scaled twice.  First from 150% to 100% by the winforms plumbing.  Then back up by the dpi virtualization of the OS.  Scaling down is quite often problematic.  The "chopped window" problem is caused by Winforms seeing the faked monitor size that the dpi virtualization provides.  Your form has a design size that is too large for that.  So it reduces the size to fit.  Yes, you can call that a bug, it should apply the limit *after* scaling down.  Not the only thing that can wrong, designing at 100% so it only ever scales up is certainly the most practical solution.

Comment: @HansPassant: That makes perfect sense, and I suspected something like that was happening. Do you think there's a way around the bug apart from designing with 100% ?

Comment: There is no workaround.  Not easy to fix for Microsoft either, that's why it isn't getting fixed.  Keeping an eye on new framework releases is wise, all of the recent ones had dpi problem tweaks.  But being able to switch VS2017 in dpi virtualization mode is a strong hint they threw up their hands btw, the down-scaling problems are pretty fundamental.  Text needs proportionally more space at lower font point sizes, nasty.

Answer (score 0):

I've found two half-solutions so far:

First is upgrading to Visual Studio 2017 (which allows you to force 100% scaling in VS Forms designer even in 150% Windows scaling)

Second is keeping with an earlier version of Visual Studio (including VS 2010), but making sure Windows is set to 100% scaling. If you've only just changed the scaling setting, make sure to log out and in of Windows to ensure the scaling is applied appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple workaround is to create a `Panel` Control that is the size you desire for the window, send it to the first layer (right click the control in the designer> send to back). Then set the form to `AutoResize` to fit that control. (also set `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink` in case the form appears larger than it should)

This works great if you need `Fixed` forms but for `Resizable` forms you might want some extra code that resizes this panel when the form's resize event happens.